# Fetch Room which is having minimal bookings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am having a booking table as the design below, where for a single room i may have multiple bookings, which is represented by RoomBookingID, where for a single room multiple dates with multiple time slots will be saved.

```
RoomBookingID --> Date (values like 1,2..)
RoomID --> int (values like 1,2,3)
MeetingDate --> date (values like '2014-06-04','2014-06-05')
StartTime --> time (values like '10:00:00')
EndTime --> time (values like '13:00:00')
```

From the above table, i want to fetch the room (roomid) which is having minimal bookings based on the RoomBookingID

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have not tried anything, since struck with this logic

Comment: @user3682227 Struck with logic? I find it amusing...

Comment: What kind of SQL are you working on ? MySQL ? SQLServer ? Oracle ? Whatever ?

Comment: For each meeting date, which room is having minimal bookings, need to find this logic

Comment: I think you could `ORDER BY` bookings `asc` number and then limit to the top 1 room.

Comment: You must have some idea how to approach this problem or where to start.

Comment: I need roomid for each date

Comment: In what period, forever? Do you want minimal booking count or duration?

Comment: minimal booking for each date

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT RoomID, COUNT(RoomBookingID) as bookings
FROM tablename
GROUP BY RoomID
ORDER BY bookings DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

We count the different "RoomBookingID"s for each room and then we sort them based on the results. The smallest number is the first, but this does not means that the second has not the same bookings.

Comment: we dont have LIMIT keyword in sql rite, is any other option need to be replaced?

Comment: You don't need to use LIMIT just take the first row. I don't know if GROUP BY and ORDER BY is supported by rite but probably they are.

Comment: Iam able to get the bookings by grouping based on dates as below

SELECT MeetingDate, COUNT(MeetingTypeID) as bookingsCount, MeetingTypeID AS RoomID
FROM [#TrnRoomBookings1]
GROUP BY MeetingDate,MeetingTypeID

where from above result i need to get minimum booked roomid for each date